# "System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified" (but I am not attempting to modify the collection)

Tags: c#, enumeration, invalidoperationexception

I'm working in Visual Studio Professional 2013, coding in C# with WPF.

I am enumerating over the entries in a dictionary to concatenate a MySQL query, however my function keeps raising an exception

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation
>   may not execute."

I've done some research and the only cases I've found of this exception involve attempts to add or remove entries to a collection while enumerating over it. In my case I'm not even changing entries, let alone adding or removing from the collection. Does anyone see something I'm missing here?  I've even tried locking the collection before enumerating without success.

Code:

```
 public void UpdateGenericIndexed(Dictionary<string,string> tags)
    {
        lock (tags)
        {
            bool failed = false;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();     
            StringBuilder cmdEnd = new StringBuilder();

            if (tags.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in tags) //Exception is thrown here
                {
                    if (entry.Key != null && entry.Value != null && !failed)
                    {
                        sb.Append("when \"");
                        sb.Append(entry.Key.ToString());
                        sb.Append("\" then \"");
                        sb.Append(entry.Value.ToString());
                        sb.Append("\" ");
                        cmdEnd.Append("\"");
                        cmdEnd.Append(entry.Key.ToString());
                        cmdEnd.Append("\",");
                        failed = false;
                    }
                    else
                        failed = true;
                }
```

The this is called periodically from a timer. I have also noticed *sometimes* while attempting to debug, that somehow the code executes past the conditional checking the dictionary count but the count shows 0 when the code is halted

[This Picture shows a screenshot of the fault _count=85, but tags.Count and tags_temp.Count both equal Zero. How is that possible?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNX91.png)

Thanks for the help, and this is my first post so my apologies in advance if I've strayed from any formatting rules.

Comment: Have you tried another locker object?

Comment: You have to provide more detailed exception info...
It is not clear from what you have  shared now....
Can you please tell in which line your code is throwing the exception?
I tried your above code but no error occurred for me....@A Moghadam

Comment: How do you call this function? What is the variable you pass here?

Comment: edited my initial question to show where the exception is thrown and how i call this function.

@MagisterCrazy the varible is a  dictionary<string,string>  I have a table in my database with variable names and their respective values, this function takes a dictionary of variables/values and throws them into the database table.  There is more code in the function but I edited the sample to only show the parts relevant to the problem

Comment: @Valentin: Yes, the first thing i tried was declaring a new object just for the purpose of locking this function. It did not make a difference

Comment: Is it possible, that you downloading data from the database at the same time when you try to run this code (as you said, it's timer based, so there can be an issue).

Comment: @MagisterCrazy it might not be the best practice but I have a locker object that i use for any functions that read or write the table to avoid that kind of conflict. And when data is read I throw it into a dictionary to be processed so I can't imagine how the database being updated would affect the dictionary that is being read to parse a string.

Comment: Probably some completely different function on another thread is updating `tags` while the function you show is trying to enumerate it.

Comment: Can you please share the whole context? Your code cannot generate the exception by itself. We should see all the place where you use the reference tags.

Comment: I managed to fix this by putting a lock on the section of code that populates the dictionary and then sends it to this function.  I guess I had mistakenly assumed that when this function executes it uses copies of the parameters passed to it or something.